# I am getting an error: while running launch file

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-lunar, ros-hydro, ros-kinetic, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Error message:**

```
roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/map_server]. Please check all <node> 'name' attributes to make sure they are unique. Also check that $(anon id) use different ids. The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

**Launch file:**

```
<launch>
    <include file ="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/minimal.launch" />
    <arg name="map_file" default="/home/gab/catkin_ws/src/gabS/Desktop.yaml" />
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />
    <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/amcl_demo.launch" />
    <include file="$(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/launch/view_navigation.launch" />
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306465/i-am-getting-an-error:-while-running-launch-file/) by [gab](https://answers.ros.org/users/38162/gab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-10-23**:
There's probably another node tag with the name `map_server` in the launch files you include here. In ROS every node must have unique **name** tag attribute (as the error message describes). You probably wanted to use only one of the `map_server` node, therefore delete the remaining ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @l4ncelot said you have another `map_server` node with the same name launched in `amcl_demo.launch` so just get rid of your node in your launch file (since you only need one `map_server` ) and put the `map_file` argument in the `amcl` node :

```
<launch>
    <include file ="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/minimal.launch" />
    <arg name="map_file" default="/home/gab/catkin_ws/src/gabS/Desktop.yaml" />
  
    <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/amcl_demo.launch">
         <arg name="map_file" value="$(arg map_file)"/>
    </include>
    <include file="$(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/launch/view_navigation.launch" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1